# How can I pass arguments to a script executed by sh read from stdin?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I download some shell script from *example.com* with `wget` and execute it immediately by streaming stdout of `wget` via a pipe to stdin of the `sh` command.

`wget -O - http://example.com/myscript.sh | sh -`

How can I pass arguments to the *script*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `-s` option while invoking `bash` for passing an argument to the shell script being downloaded:

```
wget -O - http://example.com/myscript.sh | bash -s 'arg1' 'arg2'
```

As per `man bash`:

> ```
> -s   If the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain after option processing,
>      then commands are  read  from the  standard  input. This option allows
>      the positional parameters to be set when invoking an interactive shell.
> ```

Answer (score 13):

While the accepted answer is correct, it does only work on `bash` and not on `sh` as the initial poster requested.

To do this in `sh` you'll have to add `--`:

```
curl https://example.com/script.sh | sh -s -- --my-arg
```